# NSURLConnection initWithRequest is deprecated

Tags: ios, gmail-api, xcode7

I am adopting the **Gmail API** in iOS and I am getting the warning:

> initWithRequest is deprecated

in the following line:

```
connection_ = [[connectionClass alloc] initWithRequest:request_ delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
```

The  line is in the source file GTMHTTPFetcher.m of the API library.

**What is the substitute for the deprecated `-initWithRequest:` method?**

Comment: Doesn't the error mention the replacement? What do the official docs (class reference) for `NSURLConnection` say?

Comment: The error is as follows: google-api-objective-client/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPFetcher.m:459:46: 'initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use NSURLSession (see NSURLSession.h) and the official docs have not mentioned anything about what to use instead of initWithRequest  @NicolasMiari

Comment: I see... (slightly) Bad news, then. see my answer.

Comment: Please flag correct answer! Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the whole `NSURLConnection` API has been deprecated in iOS 9. Existing apps will continue to work, but new builds (linked against iOS SDK) must use the newer `NSURLSession` API.

Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial).
Also, of course, check the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/).

Answer (score 41):

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS 9. You can use `NSURLSession` instead which exists since iOS 7.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
            // do something with the data 
        }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about the completionHandler : here's an **one liner**.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request] resume];
```